# C# Calculator working incorrectly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The calculator works fine if I keep using the same operator(*, /, +, -) but if for example I decide to multiply the total of two added numbers it'll give me a wrong answer. I've looked for a solution but can't seem to find one.

```
   public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool multiply = false;
    bool divide = false;
    bool add = false;
    bool subtract = false;

    private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "1";
    }

    private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "2";
    }

    private void btnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "3";
    }

    private void btnFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "4";
    }

    private void btnFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "5";
    }

    private void btnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "6";
    }

    private void btnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "7";
    }

    private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "8";
    }

    private void btnNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "9";
    }

    private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + "0";
        }
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }

    private void btnDecimalPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + ".";
        }
    }

    private void btnNegative_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDisplay.Text.Contains("-"))
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text.Remove(0,1);
        }
        else
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = "-" + txtDisplay.Text;
        }
    }

    private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDisplay.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            multiply = true;
            txtDisplay.Tag = txtDisplay.Text;
            txtDisplay.Text = "";
        }
    }


    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDisplay.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            add = true;
            txtDisplay.Tag = txtDisplay.Text;
            txtDisplay.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDisplay.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            subtract = true;
            txtDisplay.Tag = txtDisplay.Text;
            txtDisplay.Text = "";
        }
    }
    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (multiply)
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisplay.Tag) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Text = dec.ToString();
        }
        if (divide)
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisplay.Tag) / Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Text = dec.ToString();
        }
        if (add)
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisplay.Tag) + Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Text = dec.ToString();
        }
        if (subtract)
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisplay.Tag) - Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Text = dec.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDisplay.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            divide = true;
            txtDisplay.Tag = txtDisplay.Text;
            txtDisplay.Text = "";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is backwards. You have UI values that you transform into numbers to do calculations. You should have numbers that are used to build UI values.

Comment: woah.  I would combine most if not all of your events into one then determine the sender for the sake of my scrolly wheel

Comment: Are you saying that when you type in a sequence like `1+2*3` you get `9`, but you want `7`?

Comment: any chance you could do some solid testing and show us what answers you are getting from what inputs?

Comment: Specifically what buttons do you push to produce the wrong answer?  What answer is displayed?

Comment: You never reset your `multiply` etc. variables.  Once the user has hit the Multiply button, every Equals will be a multiply even if it's something else as well.  You'd be better off with a single `operator` variable that was set to "multiply", "add", etc.  Then they'd be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Its because when you click an operator button you set the boolean to `true` but you don't set the other values to `false` so once you have 2 selected both operators will fire in your `btnEquals_Click` event.

Comment: In addition to what the others are saying, you don't appear to ever clear your operator flags. You could have multiple operations occurring when you hit your equals button.

Comment: This is probably a rounding issue with converting strings to decimals, but you are going to need to be more specific.  Could you provide us an example of the actions you take to produce a correct answer, and one where it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Look at your `btnEquals_Click` event. Someone chooses to add, so `add = true` and it's the only `if` block that executes - everything good so far.

Then someone chooses to multiply, so now `multiply = true`, but `add = true` as well, so now you're multiplying *and* adding. If someone goes through all the operators, then (because you're never clearing your operator flags), every number thereafter will be multiplied, then divided, then added, and finally subtracted.

To fix it, you could create a method that clears the operators:

```
private void ResetOperatorFlags()
{
    multiply = false;
    divide = false;
    add = false;
    subtract = false;
}
```

Then call it before you perform an operation on the number:

```
private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtDisplay.Text == "")
        return;

    ResetOperatorFlags();

    multiply = true;
    txtDisplay.Tag = txtDisplay.Text;
    txtDisplay.Text = "";
}
```

Finally, in your `btnEquals_Click` event, use `else if`... you won't really need it after clearing the flags, but there's no sense in testing every flag if only one can be set at a time:

```
private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (multiply)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (divide)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: @chancea, thanks you solved my problem, and thanks to everyone else who helped aswell.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that you aren't clearing your operation commands.  i.e. you set it to Add, but you never clear the Add when you set it to Multiply.  If you look in the btnEquals_Click method, it's possible to have several operations active at once, and it will execute all of them.

Comment: yep, i'll also add that he should use a enum and a switch statement rather then 4 bools and many ifs

Comment: agreed, I had to look at a LOT of code before I saw the problem there :)

Comment: Yea, sorry for the long blocks of code. Still trying to get the hang of C#

Comment: @DiegoAR: You can make all buttons use btn_Click and typecast sender to a button and get its value (`int.Parse(btn.Text)`) but the GUI makes it easy to do it the way you did and copy/paste. Also btnEquals_Click has so many duplicate lines. `txtDisplay.Text = dec.ToString();` could be outside of all the if blocks. The if should be a switch with a throw exception as default. Tag & text could be its own variables outside of the if or switch block.